# OpenFeint in Cocos2D

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, openfeint

Are there any full tutorials, with sample code, of using OpenFeint with Cocos2D?

Comment: now OpenFeint is outdated, try GREE for its alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seem to be several tutorials out there; here are a few:

[Integrating OpenFeint with Cocos2D-iPhone Applications](http://pocketworx.com/?p=80)
[Tutorial – Implement OpenFeint into Cocos2d Game](http://paulsonapps.wordpress.com/2010/05/26/tutorial-implement-openfeint-into-cocos2d-game/)
[Integrating OpenFeint with Cocos2D for iPhone](http://frozenorange.net/2010/03/22/integrating-openfeint-with-cocos2d-for-iphone/)
[OpenFeint Integration with cocos2d](http://iphonetoptips.blogspot.com/2010/10/openfeint-integration-with-cocos2d.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for sample code, you could check out this complete game with sample code, including open feint integration:

http://kwigbo.com/post/680329612/artifice-open-source

This and several other good examples can be found at

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:sample_games

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to implement challenges, here's the best tutorial I've found:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/12300

Answer (score 0):

Now OpenFeint is outdated and GREE is alternative for OpenFeint. Its officially announced by OpenFeint team.